# Developing UCWA online for iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ucwa

For developing UCWA online for iOS application, what can I do for Signin URL when registered the application to Azure AD.
Please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following resource. You first need to register an app in Azure AD which would give you access token and provide access to Skype for Business. Then you will actually sign in into Skype for Business Online.

[Setting up Azure Ad authentication and access to Skype for Business Online](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2016/03/skype-web-sdk-online-setting-everything-up-step-by-step-guide/)

[Sign in to Skype for Business Online](http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2015/04/learn-skype-web-sdk-day-1-logging-in/)

Comment: "Error 403 - This web app is stopped." we page you link does not work

Comment: Open the site and then when you click the chapter all pages are down. not working anymore. can you please make it PDF or google doc and share?

Comment: Its already hosted here    https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Learn-Skype-Web-SDK-in-30-418fe989